# Crash on dismising UIAlertController

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uialertcontroller

- On viewdidappear,  I present an alertcontroller and call an async db request
  once the data is received, I will dismiss the alert in main
  thread automatically without any user interaction.
- At this point, my app is getting crashed but not able to reproduce.
  This is the crash that happening randomly and very rare to reproduce.
- I don't have any idea about this issue. I suspect that I am
  dismissing the alert while it is in the middle of presenting. Have
  anyone faced this kind of crash/error.

This is the crash report

```
> Crashed: com.apple.main-thread 0  UIKit                              
> 0x255dd374 -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 95 1 
> UIKit                               0x255dd371
> -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 92 2  UIKit                               0x255e0a85 __56-[UIPresentationController
> runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_2 + 192 3  UIKit           
> 0x253be157 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] +
> 90 4  UIKit                               0x252cbba5
> -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 540 5  UIKit                               0x252cb685 -[UIViewAnimationState
> sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 204 6  UIKit                
> 0x252cb57f -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 78 7 
> QuartzCore                          0x2332c699
> CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 252 8  libdispatch.dylib  
> 0x2088580f _dispatch_client_callout + 22 9  libdispatch.dylib         
> 0x20893ba9 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1524 10
> CoreFoundation                      0x20cd9b6d
> __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8 11 CoreFoundation                      0x20cd8067 __CFRunLoopRun + 1574
> 12 CoreFoundation                      0x20c27229 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
> + 520 13 CoreFoundation                      0x20c27015 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108 14 GraphicsServices                   
> 0x22217ac9 GSEventRunModal + 160 15 UIKit                             
> 0x252f9189 UIApplicationMain + 144 16 MY_Test_App    0x1b6397 main
> (main.m:16) 17 libdyld.dylib                       0x208cf873 start +
> 2
```

Comment: Try to rephrase your question. Crashes in some viewcontroller are too general, add more information regarding of when it happened.

Comment: The problem is, I didn't get any information from crash log. I think, I already added the info regarding when it happens.

Comment: Show the code you have, particularly around animations

Comment: I'm having the same problem, how did you fix it?